# why the sleep function is executed in an arithmatic operation ?

Tags: mysql

In  a normal SQL query  For Mysql version > 5.0

```
Select A, B FROM table where id =1
```

if an attacker injects 1-sleep(10) for the id parameter, why does the database sleep ? What is the role of hyphen here ?  Isn't it invalid syntax (arithmetic operation of integer and a function)  ?

Answer (score 3):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_sleep says:

> Sleeps (pauses) for the number of seconds given by the duration argument, then returns 0.

In other words, it returns an integer, which is perfectly okay to use in an arithmetic expression.

Hyphen (`-`) is the [arithmetic operator for subtraction](http://%20https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/arithmetic-functions.html#operator_minus).

I would infer that when an attacker injects a sleep, they're trying to test if your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. They can time the response to see if it lengthens when they add a sleep with a longer duration. This would confirm that they can exploit your code in other ways.

Comment: SELECT emp_no, first_name, last_name FROM employees  where 
    emp_no  = 498809-sleep(2) ;                                                                                          when I run this command in mysql console, the database does not return output. could you please tell me why is that ?

Comment: I would guess that there are no rows matching that condition.